# streaming to correct network interface

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming

I have IP cam that supports RTSP streaming. It's connected to router with 2 network cards with IP1 and IP2 addresses. I make 2 connections to IP cam by IP1 and IP2 addresses from the same IP and I need to receive corresponding streams thru correct network card, but both streams (RTP over UDP) go thru IP1. How this can be resolved?

I don't know if RTSP server binds UDP sockets to corresponding IP and I don't know what IP stack is in IP cam (weak end system or strong end system). I haven't found anything interesting in router configuration. As I understand, routing table cannot help me cos I'm connected from the same IP, is it right? Also

Sorry for incomplete info but it's all I have at the moment. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try 'nmap' (http://www.nmap.org), it's got OS/tcp stack fingerprinting capabilities. It could identify whatever's running inside the camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, received reply from router vendor, and no, it's not possible to send UDP packet over particular network interface. it uses load balancing that cannot be turned off